# Using Span produces an exception in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, stackalloc

I have added the reference `System.Memory` to a Console C# project in VS 2019 to use `System.Span` structure. But the following code produces an exception:

```
using System;
class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Span<int> numbers = stackalloc int[3];            
    }
}
```

The exception message is:

> Inner Exception FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I solve the problem and remove the exception?

Comment: What is your project's Target Framework?

Comment: @yaakov the default: 4.7.2

Comment: Have you gone to the Project Settings and set "Allow unsafe Code" to true? Anyways try to retarget your application, because the error says that ist missing a framework dependency. You can retarget your porject by selecting another target framework, and then resetting after compliling.

Comment: @RenéCarannante Yes unsafe is active but Span is not going to be unsafe. Changing target adds a lot of compiler errors. VS is installed normally. have you tested the code in VS?

Comment: @nano your code works fine for me, it is not a problem with your code, rather somethings odd with your framework, as you can see the error says that a file wasnt found, not that you did something wrong. As I said **retarget** your project, if that doesnt help reinstall your SDK.

Comment: When you say that you added a reference to System.Memory, how exactly did you do that?